# Safe mode in Windows 7 on Bootcamp?

Tags: windows-7, macbook, bios, boot-camp, safe-mode

How do I boot my Windows 7 partition to safe mode if it is installed into BOOTCAMP? On normal PC computers, you normally see the BIOS getting started and prompting you to press something (normally F8) to enter different boot up methods. However, on the Mac's Bootcamp, there's no text that says any info about such. It directly goes to the Windows 7 loading screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You won't see the text show up but it is booting in the background.

So, just do as normal; you should be able to keep hitting F8 so you still get into the menu...

Comment: Yup. Same thing with grub. As soon as you select the windows option, hold F8.

Comment: Remember though that it will use your Bootcamp setting for the Fn keys. If it's set to use the keys normally (i.e. F1, F2, etc), this will work. If it's set to do the function (i.e. Brightness, Volume) normally, press Fn+F8 after selecting Windows

Comment: @Luke: Excellent observation. I always forget that.

Comment: I use the functions in my Mac side, but use the F1, F2 etc all the time in Windows

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I also have another question but I guess I'll ask it here instead of creating a new thread. Umm, how do I open the BIOS setup for the Windows side of my MacBook in Bootcamp?

Comment: Ummm, BIOS is available before Windows. You should post as a separate question what you are trying to do, then let us suggest the best avenues.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is *Windows 8* only, but this worked for me:

- Open the `Start` menu, click the `Power` button, then **hold `Shift`** while clicking `Restart`
- After a few seconds, a full-screen menu appears
- Click `Troubleshoot` > `Advanced options` > `Command Prompt`
- The computer will now reboot. Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> to make sure the Bootcamp menu appears, then select `Windows`.

Note that the `X:` appears to be mapped to a 'clean' Windows install in the command prompt.