# Boot Camp running Windows 10 gets error 0x000000e on startup

Tags: windows-10, boot, macbook, boot-camp

I have a MacBook Pro with touch bar 13" with Boot Camp running Windows 10.

After resizing the HDD, Windows 10 automatically goes to repair mode and gives the error: `0xc000000e`

I do see the Windows partition by holding <kbd>Option</kbd> key on startup.

[image]

Comment: What happens when Windows goes through repair mode? Also, is there anything significant that you need on the Windows 10 installation, or could it be reinstalled?

Comment: problem is that repair does not go through

Comment: Can you get to the **System Recovery Options** in Repair mode?

Comment: it boots into windows partition and then for a second it shows preparing automatic repair and then stops at a screen shown that error, I should post a screenshot

Comment: @Ashton, by pressing F8, I can only see options from F1 to F9, but none of them works

Comment: no other options, no system recovery options

Comment: Can you get to the Command Prompt window from pressing **F8**?

Comment: I can't, pressing F1-F9 just goes back to where it was

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63768/discussion-between-ashton-and-ikel).

Answer (score 0):

As was found in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63768/discussion-between-ashton-and-ikel), it seems that the options are:

### Rebuild the BCD

1. Find a way to access the command prompt window.

   - This may be possible by doing one of the following:

     - Open **System Recovery Options** on startup and select Command Prompt.
     - Boot Windows in Safe Mode. —[Safe mode in Windows 7 on Bootcamp?](https://superuser.com/questions/352836/safe-mode-in-windows-7-on-bootcamp)
2. Type the following command in the Command Prompt window and press **Enter**:

   ```
   bootrec /rebuildbcd
   ```
3. If bootrec finds a Windows installation, press <kbd>Y</kbd> to rebuild the BCD.
4. Restart Windows to confirm that the problem is fixed.
5. In the case that it isn't, type the following command in the Command Prompt window and press **Enter**: (Ensure the **C** is replaced with the letter of your Windows partition.)

   ```
   chkdsk C: /f
   ```
6. Allow chkdsk to resolve any problems that occur. Do not interrupt the process.
7. Once it has completed, restart Windows to confirm that the problem is fixed.

### Repair the Windows installation

1. On the MacOS, open **Macintosh HD**, click **Applications**, select **Utilities**, and open **Boot Camp Assistant**.
2. Choose **Start Windows Installation**.
3. Insert the Windows installation disk into the Mac and restart.
4. When prompted, press any key to boot from the Windows installation media.
5. Follow the usual Windows installation prompts and select **Repair your computer** when prompted.

**NOTE**: As the error `0x000000e` indicates a corruption in data has taken place, it is possible that data will be missing. Following the steps above will not guarantee that all data will be protected.

Comment: repair windows installation method won't work, because if bootcamp partition exists, the next time bootcamp assistant gets started it will only ask if you want to remove bootcamp partition and restore disk to a single partition.  also, I cannot boot into safe mode, have tried already